# MODX SimpleSearch vs. AdvSearch

Tags: php, search, modx, modx-revolution

I planned to implement a search function on my site. I tested both SimpleSearch and AdvSearch.

SimpleSearch was easy to take in use but I was not able to get AdvSearch working in the ajax mode but only in the normal mode. Ajax is not that important so I can use normal pagination. I am still unsure which extra should I use and asking for opinions.

- Is it possible to search also template variables with SimpleSearch? At least, AdvSearch seems to support that.
- SimpleSearch seems to be more popular than AdvSearch. AdvSearch has not been updated in 5 years. Would SimpleSearch be a safer choice?
- Any other recommendations?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several times when choosing between these two, I leaned in favor of `SimpleSearch` snippet. Yes, you're right `SimpleSearch` doesn't support TV search basically (previously there was search driver support as snippet parameter - now you can specify your own search driver with TV search option via `System Settings` (please see attached screenshot) ). As for me I've just moved all necessary data to basic resource fields where `SimpleSearch` works perfectly.

[image]

However, you may encounter other limitations with it, such as performance issues if you use it on a site with hundreds of pages. My option was this - I made a custom snippet, did some of the work (f.e I prepared a list of resources where to search and passed it to the `id` parameter, this list in my case had to be calculated non-trivially), and then I called it through `runSnippet`

Comment: Thank you @Anton Tarasov. I did also my own comparison and ended up choosing SimpleSearch. It works surprisingly well. My site is so small that there are no performance issues. I think SimpleSearch is also searching my TVs even though I have not changed the search driver.

Moving all necessary data to resource fields sounds also a good solution but may not pay back if there are no performance issues. Especially, when I am using some Extras that use TVs.